# How does GWT/Errai apps deal with Search Engine crawlers

Tags: java, gwt, errai

In the specification [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

A URL: `www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value`

Will become: `www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value`

However, typical Errai applications, have this form `ajax.html#!SomePage;key=value`

Is there a way for Errai to match the specification?